# cpu afinity mask for 32 CPU cores

Tags: cpu, affinity, setthreadaffinitymask

I have 32 available CPU cores and the affinity mask is:

> 00ff00ff

Can someone please help me understand which CPU cores the affinity is set to, using this number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit mapping in binary (base 2) to select which cores you have enabled. 0 for off and 1 for on.  Make groups of four blocks to with enough groups to represent all the cores you have.  Each bit represents a core. Choose if each is on or off.  Take the resulting 4-bit number and convert to hexadecimal (base 16).  This will give you the hexadecimal code. For 00ff 00ff, it is 0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 1111 1111.  So, cores 0 - 7 and 16 -23 are off with 8 - 15 and 24 - 32 turned on.  You can also use a calculator set to programming mode.  Windows 10 default calculator has that function.